# Unable to Access Save Custom SQL in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I created a dashboard in which I have created a custom SQL with name "Final PF". Now I want to create another custom SQL by using existing custom SQL "Final PF".
But when I want to do this it gives me an error: `"column "Final PF" does not exist"`

[image]

What should I do?